# Getting wrong output in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing an Android app from which I have to retrieve the data from MySQL. But I am getting the wrong output.

The table name is blood and the structure is as follows

[image: structure of the table]

The php code is as follows

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","databasename");

$city = "HYDERABAD";
$blood = "APOSITIVE";

$sql = "select name,blood,age,lastdonated,mobile,email,state,city,sex from blood where upper(blood) = '$blood' OR lower(blood) = '$blood' AND upper(city) = '$city' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000 ";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('name'=>$row[0],
'blood'=>$row[1],
'age'=>$row[2],
'donated'=>$row[3],
'number'=>$row[4],
'email'=>$row[5],
'state'=>$row[6],
'city'=>$row[7]
));
}

echo json_encode(array("feedAnegative"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The output is

```
{
   "feedAnegative":[
      {
         "name":"saicharan",
         "blood":"APOSITIVE",
         "age":"19",
         "donated":"0000-00-00",
         "number":"8794511258",
         "email":"dsaicharan219@gmail.com",
         "state":"andhrapradesh",
         "city":"vijayawada"
      },
      {
         "name":"b",
         "blood":"Apositive",
         "age":"20",
         "donated":"0000-00-00",
         "number":"1234567892",
         "email":"b@gmail.com",
         "state":"Telangana",
         "city":"khammam"
      },
      {
         "name":"a",
         "blood":"APOSITIVE",
         "age":"20",
         "donated":"0000-00-00",
         "number":"1245863921",
         "email":"a@gmail.com",
         "state":"telangana",
         "city":"hyderabad"
      }
   ]
}
```

In the above json feed I should just get the data related to city = hyderabad.
But I am getting all the records in the table where blood is APOSITIVE. Where is the error?

Comment: It's impossible that you are using SQL Server. The mysqli extension (as the name suggests) only works with MySQL.

Comment: BTW, a `_ci` collation should be more than enough to perform case insensitive search, you don't need to UPPER() and LOWER() around.

Comment: Thanks Álvaro González for the edit. Its mysql. And I got the answer for my question. Some one has posted the correct answer and deleted it. I Thank him/her a lot for too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What determines rows in result-set is the SQL query sent to MySQL, not the PHP code around:

```
select name,blood,age,lastdonated,mobile,email,state,city,sex
from blood
where upper(blood) = 'APOSITIVE' OR lower(blood) = 'APOSITIVE' AND upper(city) = 'HYDERABAD'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

If you don't use parenthesis to set operator priority, [default ones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) apply:

> Operator precedences are shown in the following list, from **highest precedence to the lowest**. Operators that are shown together on
>   a line have the same precedence.
>
> ```
> INTERVAL
> BINARY, COLLATE
> !
> - (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
> ^
> *, /, DIV, %, MOD
> -, +
> <<, >>
> &
> |
> = (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN
> BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
> NOT
> AND, &&
> XOR
> OR, ||
> = (assignment), :=
> ```

So your WHERE clause is equivalent to:

```
where upper(blood) = 'APOSITIVE' OR
    (lower(blood) = 'APOSITIVE' AND upper(city) = 'HYDERABAD')
```

Additionally, the `blood` column has `latin1_general_ci` collation so `lower(blood) = 'APOSITIVE'` can actually match (no idea why it's there to begin with).